# BeanUtils.copyProperties - how to copy the values to the custom bean reference in a collection

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

```
package A;

Class A{
  String name;
  List<ClassB> myList;

  // getters and setters
}

package A;

Class B{

}

package C;

Class A{
  String name;
  List<ClassB> myList;

  // getters and setters 
}

package C;

Class B{

}

c.ClassA c_ClassA = new c.ClassA();
a.ClassA a_ClassA = new a.ClassA();


BeanUtils.copyProperties(c_ClassA,a_ClassA);
```

a_ClassA.myList has reference to c.ClassB when the above copyProperties method is used.

Instead i'm looking for a method to copy the values from c_ClassA to a_ClassA so that a_ClassA.myList has the list of a.ClassB reference instead of c.ClassB reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the source, Luke.(Or the JavaDoc) It copies the properties and does not do any form of casting. But you could implement this behavior yourself.

I do not know of an actual implementation that does this for you, since this is not the intendet behavior.